# Why the destructor is being called twice here?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, destructor

I cannot understand why the destructor for the second object d2 is being called twice. I know these type of questions have been asked in the past but every one of them had some relevant difference than mine. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class data{
char s1[50];
static int j;
public:
    data(char s[50]){
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            s1[i] = s[i];
        }
    }
    void show(){
        cout <<"Data " << ++j <<"=" << s1 << endl;
    }
    void compare(data d){
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            if(d.s1[i] != s1[i]){
                cout << "Both Objects have different text." << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ~data(){
        cout << "Release memory allocated to " << s1 << endl;
    }
};
int data::j;
int main(){
    char str[50],str1[50];
    cin>>str;
    cin>>str1;

    data d1(str);
    data d2(str1);

    d1.show();
    d2.show();

    d1.compare(d2);

    return 0;

}
```

The Output when this code runs is:

```
 Data 1=object1
 Data 2=object2
 Both Objects have different text.
 Release memory allocated to object2
 Release memory allocated to object2
 Release memory allocated to object1
```

Comment: Because you pass by value.

Comment: When you pass `d2` to `d1.compare`, it makes a copy, and the parameter will be destructed as well.

Comment: I think it's due to `d1.compare(d2);`, you pass the d2 by value, which creates a new instance of the `data` class.

Comment: You forgot to add logging to copy ctor and assignment.

Comment: I believe that's not the same question as the designated duplicate. The difference is that the other question addresses the existence of a copy constructor, where in this it seems to be ignored, and so the answers of the other answer are not valid here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are passing the input argument to `compare` by value and not by reference.